# icons in a firefox android bootstrapped extension

Tags: firefox-addon, icons, fennec

I'm working on a bootstrapped extension for firefox android, and I have a problem with displaying icons in a new menu item:

```
    itemMenuId = window.NativeWindow.menu.add("Show more details",ico , function() {   showToast(window); });
```

in ico I wrote the uri of the icon file existing in the root of my extension (icon.png is next to bootstrap.js), using data: and file://, like described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.NativeWindow.menu.add) but the icon isn't displayed. I don't know how to fix the path for that. Beside I'm having the same problem with the iconURL in the install.rdf file, when I use chrome:// I get nothing, and when I use resource:// I get a missing image. Should I have chrome.manifest to use chrome://? and even if I don't specify the url,to let the image be displayed by default like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Install_Manifests#iconURL) it still doesn't work.

```
    <em:iconURL>resource://trackdetect/icon.png</em:iconURL>
```

I googled it ,but, I couldn't fix it. Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the  issue, just make sure you have a file named icon.png in the root of the XPI (the same folder as bootstrap.js) and the image will be used. You don't even need the  entry in the manifest. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Install_Manifests#iconURL

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I do have the icon.png in the root of the extension, but, it is not displayed. Actually, I'm wondering, maybe the problem is with the packaging of the extension, I'm using your [skeleton-addon-fxandroid on GitHub](https://github.com/mfinkle/skeleton-addon-fxandroid) (thanks by the way), but I didn't add the icon.png to the root files list to be packaged, should I ? Thank you for you time and patience.

Comment: Yes, you need to add any file to be packaged to the config. In this case, in the root files.

Answer (score 0):

[Erik Vold's guide](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/1/2/restartless-firefox-addons-part-2-includes) explains how to reference files packaged within a bootstrapped extension.

However it is strange that the icon doesn't appear at the addons list (you don't specify a iconURL, just place icon.png next to bootstrap.js, as you did). Perhaps you should check if the tool you use creates PNGs that conform to the standard.

Comment: I used that guide to get the path of the icon: 

        (function(global) global.include = function include(src) (
Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript(src, global)))(this);

var ico;
function startup(data) AddonManager.getAddonByID(data.id, function(addon) {
ico = addon.getResourceURI("icon.png").spec;
});

Comment: but, nothing happened, it's even worse, I usded to have a slight space before the label of the menu item, and when I used this it disapeard. I didn't understand the meaning of "PNGs that conform to the standard", could you please give me further explanation and thank you.